# Live SDK: await client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files?filter=folders") does not return

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, async-await, live-sdk

I'm working on a backup function for my app, and it's supposed to check if the needed folder already exists, otherwise create it.

Since I'm using VB.Net I cant use the GetCompleted event (only available in C#, which I have no experience with).

My current code in the FolderExistsOrCreate function is like this:

```
    Private Async Function FolderExistsOrCreate(ByVal Name As String) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
        Dim ID As String = Nothing
        Dim firstRecheck = True
ReCheck:
        Try
            _message = "Looking for folder..."
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Message")
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SkyDrive")
            _client = New LiveConnectClient(_session)
 'it stops here and does not go further
            Dim res = Await _client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files?filter=folders,albums")
            Dim folderData As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = DirectCast(res.Result, Dictionary(Of String, Object))
            Dim folders As List(Of Object) = DirectCast(folderData("data"), List(Of Object))

            For Each item As Object In folders
                Dim folder As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = DirectCast(item, Dictionary(Of String, Object))
                If folder("name").ToString = Name Then
                    ID = folder("id").ToString()
                    _message = "Folder exists..."
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Message")
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SkyDrive")
                End If
            Next

            If ID = Nothing Then
                If firstRecheck = False Then
                    _message = "Creating folder failed..."
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Message")
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SkyDrive")
                    Return Nothing
                End If
                _message = "Creating folder..."
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Message")
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SkyDrive")
                Dim newFolderData As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
                newFolderData.Add("name", Name)
                _client = New LiveConnectClient(_session)
                res = Await _client.PostAsync("me/skydrive", newFolderData)
                firstRecheck = False
                GoTo ReCheck
            End If
            Return ID
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

The function is in a control I've built that contains the SignIn button, and I have added my SkyDrive class as a property to the control, and the _session it uses is the session created with the SignIn button.

I get a valid client, but all the GetAsync functions makes the app halt there without any exception. The assigned scopes does include "skydrive_update", so access is granted to create the folder too, but the code doesn't even go that far.

I've searched the Live SDK forums and the forums at MSDN for any type of answer, but all I can find are C# functions using the GetCompleted method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you explain why can't you use `GetCompleted` from VB? Almost always if you can do something in C#, you can do it in VB too.

Comment: It's not available in VB.Net, which they mention in the SDK documentation. The documentation says to do like this, but its not working.

Comment: huh? GetCompleted is a standard EventHandler delegate. There's absolutely nothing preventing you from subscribing to it in VB.NET. Also any .NET API is available to all .NET languages. Only language features differ.

Comment: The Live SDK Client do not enable GetCompleted event in VB.Net, only in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that further up your call stack, you have a call to `Wait` or `Result`, thus causing the [deadlock that I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Now with `.ConfigureAwait(False)` I get an exception `"Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Live.DynamicDictionary' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2[System.String,System.Object]'` on the line just after the `await` operation. All documentation shows c# code, but from [this blog post](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/SkyDrive-usage-through-Live-SDK-on-Windows-Phone.aspx) and my understanding it seems to be correct.

Comment: Got it to work, missed that it was `IDictionary` and not `Dictionary`

Comment: @IzaacJohansson: On WP8, the correct fix is to replace `Wait`/`Result` with `await`.